# HEROKU conectar com banco mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, gem

Estou fazendo uma engenharia reversa em um sistema, e o que desejo é utilizar a mesma base de dados do sistema antigo. Mas não estou conseguindo conectar o banco do sistema em produção com essa base. E por ser em MYSQL estou utilizando a gema mysql2, da seguinte forma:

```
heroku config:set DATABASE_URL="mysql2://meuusuariodobaco:minhasenha@link_para_o_banco_de_dados?reconnect=true"
```

E com isso minha aplicação está dando o seguinte log:

```
2016-10-11T19:57:47.792510+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H12 
desc="Request timeout" method=GET path="/" host=bsbmusical.herokuapp.com 
request_id=0fafefe8-3bfa-455c-b693-46ea7f0d3abf fwd="189.6.126.19" 
dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30001ms status=503 bytes=0
```

Detalhe: a senha possúi um caractere especial *(asterisco), isso pode ser a causa?

Tentei conectar na mão também, mas não consegui:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: meuUsuario
  password: minhaSenha
  host: meuHost
  port: portaDoBanco
```

Comment: Porque você acha que esse erro tem relação com o banco? Me parece um problema ao pegar o asset `favicon.ico`

Comment: Tem sido no banco mesmo. Fiz um teste com a gema mysql2, rodando no console do heroku de acordo com a documentação(https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2), e tem dado o mesmo erro. Não sei o que pode ser, pois quando rodo o rails localmente conectado nessa base ele vai, mas quando tento em produção não vai.

Answer (score 2):

O mysql no heroku é gerado por um add-on, você vai precisar adicioná-lo na sua app no heroku e seguir os passos de configuração - https://elements.heroku.com/addons/cleardb

Algo como:

```
# add cleardb add-ons to your app
$ heroku addons:add cleardb:ignite

# set CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL
$ heroku config:set DATABASE_URL='mysql://meuusuariodobaco:minhasenha@link_para_o_banco_de_dados?reconnect=true'

$ heroku config:set CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL='mysql://meuusuariodobaco:minhasenha@link_para_o_banco_de_dados?reconnect=true'
```

Comment: O clear DB nao funciona somente com banco deles?

Comment: Testei e continua com o mesmo erro

Comment: Só aquele erro ou tem mais algum? Posta aí pra gente tentar descobrir o que está acontecendo. 
Uma outra solução seria migrar os dados pro Postgres que daí fica bem mais fácil, já que o heroku usa por default.

Comment: É só esse erro mesmo